# Sum of dependent normally distributed random variables

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, normal-distribution, characteristic-functions

Suppose two random variables X and Y are dependent and normally distributed. Is there a way to determine the distribution of their sum using their characteristic functions alone?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Nope, the distribution could be anything, it depends on their relationship. You can do it, of course, if you have the joint distribution function (or joint charachteristic function)